# Hovering to only trigger the inner div

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to make the following jQuery with pure CSS(3)?

```
$(".js.outer").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'border': '2px inset red'});
    return false;
}, function() {
    $(this).css({'border': 'none'});
    return false;
});

$(".js.inner").hover(function(event) {
    $(this).css({'border': '2px inset blue'});
    return false;
}, function() {
    $(this).css({'border': 'none'});
    return false;
});
```

with this HTML

```
<div class="js outer">
    <div class="js inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AA9Nw/, however when I hover the inner element, the outer also gets the hover event. (with CSS)

On a side note, the jQuery one seems a bit buggy, when the mouse enters from the left or right the hover effect doesn't let go properly. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this previous question related to what you are trying to achieve. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331754/hover-effect-wont-trigger-underlying-elements

Comment: Yeah...try to separate your divs..

Comment: Why you set the HTML as parent/child elements? Can you changed it or not?

Comment: @lukeocom: I am trying to archive the opposite of what he is. I don't want the outer element to be hovered when hovering the inner element, and I want to only use CSS.

Comment: @Mojtaba: Yes, I am able to move the inner out of the outer container, however I want to know if it is possible to do with the HTML being as it is.

Comment: @mads - agreed. But that question IS related to what you are trying to do regardless, and does provide some insight to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Keep calm and try this

```
<div id="div2"></div> <div id="div3"></div>
```

[No Javascript just only css demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CarloOV/AA9Nw/2/)

Comment: Again, this is not the same HTML-structure. Can it be done with the two elements being an inner and an outer element?

Comment: The answer is answerable by `YES` or `NO`. and the answer is `YES`.=)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/hUgbQ/1/)**</kbd>

Separate your divs:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.one {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}

.two {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
}

.one:hover {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.two:hover {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solves my problem, however can it be done with the current HTML-structure?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm coding CSS for 8 years and never seen this before.